# Centering icons on website

Tags: html, css, web, icons

I have a problem.

I would like to center three icons on a website like so:
http://prntscr.com/cte4kt

Including the text under it.

I have searched on google, but I had no good results.
If somebody could show a simple example that would be really greatfull.

this is what I tried:

```
<div class="testDiv">
<img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="https://s21.postimg.org/jc5m4w0av/search.png">
<h3>Insert text</h3>
<h4>This is an actual test<br>
I really mean it lol.
</h4>

<img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="https://s21.postimg.org/jc5m4w0av/search.png">
<h3>Insert text</h3>
<h4>This is an actual test<br>
I really mean it lol.
</h4>

<img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="https://s21.postimg.org/jc5m4w0av/search.png">
<h3>Insert text</h3>
<h4>This is an actual test<br>
I really mean it lol.
</h4>
```

CSS:
http://pastebin.com/v0cc1cXg

Thankyou.

Comment: Sorry, just added what I tried

Answer (score 0):

I think you already know some basic HTML/CSS stuff so I'd recommend you use some of popular front-end frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) or [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/). It's almost copy/paste only thing.

Comment: So you mean I need to do this in Bootstrap? Not in html/css ?

Comment: @debebaz6: You don't need to. But if you wanna save time by learning more about HTML and CSS. This could be perfect for you or start here with learning HTML and CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like bootstrap or primercss which give you classes to add rows and columns to layout your content.

You could also create your own like the example I did [here](http://codepen.io/highlanderkev/pen/qaKvZp)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col3 center">
          <div class="inner-container">
            <i>icon</i>
            <div>text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col3">
      <div class="inner-container">
        <i>icon</i>
        <div>text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col3">
      <div class="inner-container">
        <i>icon</i>
        <div>text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.col3 {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
}

.inner-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Basically you need to create some type of layout container(width:100%) with three columns split by thirds(width:33.3%). Then inside each of those columns you position the contents with (text-align:center) to horizontally center align the content and vertically align it via something like top:30% or if you could also do an inline-block with vertical-align: middle.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your reply, the problem is fixed now